# /dev/ttyUSB0 file disappears from dev directory while using device

Tags: usb

I am trying to connect my IC 7300 Ham radio to my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop via USB. I have had it operate properly a time or two providing rig control and audio. The problem is the `/dev/ttyUSB0` file just disappears from the dev directory after a few seconds when the USB cable is plugged in. When the USB cable is removed and plugged back in it appears and then disappears. The radio works fine on a Windows machine, so I don't think it is a problem with the Ham radio.

Below is the `dmesg` from the moment the USB is plugged in until the device is disconnected.

```
dmesg -w
1587.018767] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[ 1587.195832] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=2046, bcdDevice= 1.25
[ 1587.195845] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1587.201094] hub 4-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1587.202999] hub 4-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1587.502767] usb 4-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[ 1587.649837] usb 4-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1587.649849] usb 4-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1587.649854] usb 4-2.1: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 1587.649859] usb 4-2.1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 1587.649862] usb 4-2.1: SerialNumber: IC-7300 02046571
[ 1587.655944] cp210x 4-2.1:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 1587.660093] usb 4-2.1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1587.746776] usb 4-2.4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd
[ 1588.045851] usb 4-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=2901, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1588.045864] usb 4-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1588.045870] usb 4-2.4: Product: USB Audio CODEC 
[ 1588.045874] usb 4-2.4: Manufacturer: Burr-Brown from TI              
[ 1588.131501] input: Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2.4/4-2.4:1.3/0003:08BB:2901.0005/input/input27
[ 1588.195503] hid-generic 0003:08BB:2901.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC ] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2.4/input3
[ 1594.255034] usb 4-2.1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 1594.257456] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1594.257517] cp210x 4-2.1:1.0: device disconnected
```

Comment: Your ham radio may be drawing too much current from the USB port. Do you have access to a **POWERED** USB hub?

Comment: Thanks I give it a try.

Comment: karel, thanks for help with edits

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: Problem resolved. Issue seemed to be associated with brltty. I used [apt-get autoremove brltty].  Everything is working fine. Thanks to all for help on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue in the brltty daemon which is causing the serial device to shutdown.

If you aren't using brltty (for braille touch reading devices) then you can safely remove that package :

```
apt remove brltty
```

The serial USB device will stay connected after this.

Comment: Updated to ubuntu 22 and my ttyUSB stopped working. This fixed it. It's incredible they ruined something so basic as the usb serial ports.