# Getting Pronterface with Python running on Ubuntu 22

Tags: python

I'm looking a way to continue using my RepRap Mendel Tricolor to work on Ubuntu 22. Default software has been printrun/Pronterface https://www.pronterface.com/ but it seems the project has not been supported for a while. Python packages required are not found anymore, as required installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-serial python-wxgtk2.8 python-pyglet python-tk 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-serial
E: Unable to locate package python-wxgtk2.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python-wxgtk2.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-wxgtk2.8'
E: Unable to locate package python-pyglet
```

I have also added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
```

but this did not make a difference.

After all the attempts and installing wxPyhton 4.1.1, the pronterface.py results still errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/./pronterface.py", line 30, in <module>
    from printrun.pronterface import PronterApp
  File "xxx/primtrun/pronterface.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import pronsole
  File "xxx/printrun/pronsole.py", line 32, in <module>
    from appdirs import user_cache_dir, user_config_dir, user_data_dir
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appdirs'
```

How to get the backing printing? Other software? Appimage etc. of pronterface with dependence included? Other repository to install missing components?

Answer (score 2):

### The project is actively maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/), but the [website](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/commit/94290908f688e8403e6b409645dba2e5a4bd5534) has not been updated since 2015.

You were following outdated installation instructions.
According to the [README](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun#ubuntudebian) of the project, it is now available in the official repositories.
Enter the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo apt install printrun
```

(It will automatically install pronsole, pronterface and plater as dependencies)

---

To ensure that you don't run into a dependency hell remove `trusty` from `sources.list`.

Comment: Thanks from the quick answer! This solved the issue, with: "apt remove brltty" as described at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411463/dev-ttyusb0-file-disappears-from-dev-directory-while-using-device

Comment: @mtp I am not sure how brltty is related to this, feel free to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418862/edit) my answer to add more information.